# turn pandas groupby results into a json dict array

Tags: python, json, pandas

i have the following groupby results as a dataframe called grouped:

```
        long_url            counts 
3   reddit.com  542 
2   linkedin.com    529 
4   twitter.com 525 
1   google.com  502 
0   github.com  476 
5   youtube.com 469
```

i would like to turn the results into a json dict array like this:

```
[{"reddit.com": 542}, {"linkedin.com" : 529}]
```

currently i have

```
import json

grou=json.dumps(grouped.reset_index(drop=True).to_dict(orient='records'))
grou
```

it gives me:

```
'[{"long_url": "reddit.com", "counts": 542}, {"long_url": "linkedin.com",   "counts": 529}, {"long_url": "twitter.com", "counts": 525}, {"long_url": "google.com", "counts": 502}]'
```

however it differs with what i wanted to achieve.

is there any way to accomplish without the headers??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate the `values` of your `grouped` dataframe to make a list of dicts:

```py
groups = [{url: count} for [url, count] in grouped.values]
json.dumps(groups)
```

Output:

```
'[{"reddit.com": 542}, {"linkedin.com": 529}, {"twitter.com": 525}, {"google.com": 502}, {"github.com": 476}, {"youtube.com": 469}]'
```

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of ways to achieve that, and the above answers are all making sense. Additionally, you can achieve by using the combination of dict and zip

```
df = grouped.reset_index()
d = dict(zip(df['long_url'], df['counts']))
result = [{key:value} for key,value in d.items()]
```

Then you will see the results:

```
[{'reddit.com': 542},
 {'linkedin.com': 529},
 {'twitter.com': 525},
 {'google.com': 502},
 {'github.com': 476},
 {'youtube.com': 469}]
```

Comment: Thanks Nick for pointing it out, yeah the one whole dictionary result is not what OP expected, I just updated with adding converting the one whole dictionary to the list of dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```py
import json

your_json = '[{"long_url": "reddit.com", "counts": 542}, {"long_url": "linkedin.com",   "counts": 529}, {"long_url": "twitter.com", "counts": 525}, {"long_url": "google.com", "counts": 502}]'
 
content = json.loads(your_json)

my_json = [{item['long_url']: item['counts']} for item in content]

print(my_json)
```

### Output:

[Run it here](https://www.online-python.com/Gj7mLsAYKF)

```bash
[{'reddit.com': 542}, {'linkedin.com': 529}, {'twitter.com': 525}, {'google.com': 502}]
```